# In ASP.NET, if I deploy a missing DLL in my website's BIN folder, will it cause my App Pool to recycle?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7

We forgot to deploy a DLL to our website's bin folder (it's referenced by the website and only used occasionally).

If we copy the missing DLL into the bin folder, will this cause the App Pool to refresh?

We're using ASP.NET 2 (.NET 3.5 SP1). On Windows 2008 running IIS7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the content of ~Bin folder will restart the application.